# C++ : Throw Away threads vs Thread Pool

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization, thread-safety, threadpool

So I have a main application thread in my opengl application with all rendering and stuff. Now i need some really heavy calculation which takes about 2 3 seconds so I moved it to a seperate thread here is how I manage it:

```
 std::atomic<bool> working = false;

 void work(){
     if(!working)
     {
         working = true;
         std::thread worker(do_work);
         worker.detach();
     }
     else
     {
         // Some Updations
     }
 }

 void do_work()
 {
     // The actual work
     // working = false;
 }
```

Now i call work every frame and the actual work gets dispatched automatically once the previous one has finished.

Now my question is what will be some ways to optimize this?
Some ideas that come to my mind are have a thread pool but I am not sure if that is worth the trouble implementing? Or is there any other way?

Comment: Creating a thread every 2 seconds doesn't seem like a lot of overhead. BENCHMARK before you optimize.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I don't want to go into creating a thread pool directly just for testing as it would be quite a lot of work. Also 2 seconds is kind of a average it may be 500 ms too in some cases

Comment: Maybe start by printing something when you try to start a new thread when the old one isn't ready. You currently only have one thread and you could just have it waiting on a queue for more work, basically a 1 thread thread pool. That is trivial to make. If you often run into the case where the thread is busy you probably want <num core> threads and a proper thread pool is probably warranted.

Comment: You don't have to create a thread pool.  You already have one available to you.  Just use `std::async` with `std::launch::async`  Save the futures somewhere.  Or in the very least, create one thread, keep it alive and dispatch work to it via a queue and a `condition_variable` working with a `mutex`

Comment: Roughly, I would recommend to have a thread pool when the time interval between thread spawning is below **1 ms** (order of magnitude only).

Comment: `std::async()` Standard library says it "can" use a pool of threads.

Comment: @prapin in thw worst case i am spawning threads evevery 200 to 300 ms

Comment: In this case, you will not have any measurable performance boost by using thread pools. You could still want to use them for other reasons though (style, available in framework, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use std::launch as some people have suggested. Or you could do a google for "c++ thread pool library" and probably find something waiting for you.

But the reality is simple: writing a thread pool is close to trivial and is a good exercise. So you could write your own and learn something. As has been suggested, you can dispatch via some sort of message queue.

A work queue would be any sort of mutex & cond_var - managed FIFO, and then you can have multiple readers and multiple writers. The entries in the queue can be any sort of runnable or bound function (such as a lambda).

Fun to write and you can toss into your person library for years to come.